# FFMPEG - Overlay multipe videos over video at specified interval of time

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to overlay multiple videos over a single video at specified interval of time.

have tried with different solution but it will not work as i aspect

i am use below command to overlay video over video

```
String[] cmdWorking3 = new String[]{"-i",yourRealPath,"-i",gifVideoFile1,"-i",gifVideoFile2,"-i",gifVideoFile3,
                "-filter_complex",
                "[0][1]overlay=100:100:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v1];" +
                        "[v1][2]overlay=130:130:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v2];" +
                        "[v2][3]overlay=150:150:enable='between(t,5,6)'[v3];",
                "-map","[v3]","-map" ,"0:a",
                "-preset", "ultrafast", filePath};
```

by using above command first two video completely works fine but last one will not enable

**Edit:**

//Working perfect

```
 String[] cmdWorking11 = new String[]
                {"-i",
                        yourRealPath,
                        "-i",
                        gifVideoFile1,
                        "-i",
                        gifVideoFile2,
                        "-i",
                        gifVideoFile3,
                        "-i",
                        gifVideoFile4,

                        "-filter_complex",

                        "[1]setpts=PTS+3/TB[1d];" +
                        "[2]setpts=PTS+7/TB[2d];" +
                        "[3]setpts=PTS+10/TB[3d];" +

                        "[0][1]overlay=100:100:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v1];" +
                        "[v1][1d]overlay=130:130:enable='between(t,3,6)'[v2];" +
                        "[v2][2d]overlay=130:130:enable='between(t,7,9)'[v3];" +
                        "[v3][3d]overlay=150:150:enable='between(t,10,13)'[v4];" +

                        "[1]asetpts=PTS+3/TB[1ad];" +
                        "[2]asetpts=PTS+7/TB[2ad];" +
                        "[3]asetpts=PTS+10/TB[3ad];" +
                        "[0:a][1ad][2ad][3ad]amix=4[a]",

                        "-map", "[v4]", "-map", "[a]", "-ac", "5",

                        "-preset",
                        "ultrafast",

                        filePath};
```

Above command is perfectly works fine but audio from the overlapped video is gone,can you please help me to solve this issue.

**main Video** time Duration is about **00:15 second** and all **overlay videos are about 3 second**.

it would be great to helping out to solve this issue,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delay your 3rd overlay video to start at the time of overlay.

```
String[] cmdWorking3 = new String[]{"-i",yourRealPath,"-i",gifVideoFile1,"-i",gifVideoFile2,"-i",gifVideoFile3,
                "-filter_complex",
                "[3]setpts=PTS+5/TB[3d];" + 
                "[0][1]overlay=100:100:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v1];" +
                        "[v1][2]overlay=130:130:enable='between(t,0,2)'[v2];" +
                        "[v2][3d]overlay=150:150:enable='between(t,5,6)'[v3]",
                "-map","[v3]","-map" ,"0:a",
                "-preset", "ultrafast", filePath};
```

---

To keep audio as well, include in filter_complex

```
          [1]adelay=3000|3000[1ad];
          [2]adelay=7000|7000[2ad];
          [3]adelay=10000|10000[3ad];
          [0:a][1ad][2ad][3ad]amix=5[a]
```

Replace `-map 0:a` with `-map '[a]' -ac 2`

Comment: it will crash 
Log: Error initializing complex filters.
                                                                                  Invalid argument

Comment: [AVFilterGraph @ 0xf26d4740] No such filter: ''
                                                                                  Error initializing complex filters.
                                                                                  Invalid argument

Comment: What i need to do is overlay multiple videos over single video 
the inputs may contains are more than 3

Comment: i did not understand the concept for the same bro

Comment: why need to put delay to last added video ?

Comment: and can you please tell me the breaf info for this line '[3]setpts=PTS+5/TB[3d];'

Comment: Your overlay video is 3 seconds long but you're overlaying it at 5 seconds. Now, ffmpeg overlay takes the frame with timestamp 5s from both inputs but that's beyond the EOF of the overlay input. So, we need to change timestamps so that start of overlay video happens at timestamp 5. The syntax for that is `setpts=PTS+X/TB` where X is delay in seconds.

Comment: ok that means i should have to put time delay to last added video ?

Comment: You have to add time delay to any overlay video whose overlay doesn't start at time 0 of the base video.

Comment: ok can we talk this by tomorrow ? because my input video is dynamic and i  have to manage  those thanks for your support

Comment: hey @Mulvya i can not getting sound of overlay  video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167144/discussion-between-nd1010-and-mulvya).

Comment: need your help can you please join into chat room

Comment: thank you for your support can you please edit answer with that command which i want because i am new for FFMPEG

Comment: You have to add the new lines, not change existing ones.

Comment: as you tell me i have added at to the new line but only first video overlay with sound others are still not with sound overlay

Comment: As you told me i have update my command with existing one and added new command to new line
but still getting only first video sound (Updated cmd is in question)

Comment: Sorry, forgot about amix requirements. Use edited lines. If you have more channels in an input, add those many entries e.g. for 5 channels, `adelay=30000|30000|30000|30000|30000`

Comment: can i increase the process speed in this command i have already used **-preset** **ultrafast** command for increasing command speed

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4  -i test1.mp4 -itsoffset 2 -i test2.mp4  -i test3.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=0:0,overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,2,15)',overlay=0:0" output.mp4
```

where -itsoffset 2 mean that test3.mp4 start play at 2s, and enable='between(t,start_time,end_time)' mean this video display duration

Comment: Nice :) pretty easy